# How to stop execution of function in Clojure without exiting REPL?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

Is it possible in a Clojure REPL to stop the execution of a function without terminating the REPL session? How can I do this?

I'm using `lein repl` in bash, if it matters. I'm using Leiningen 1.7.1

Comment: Which lein version? mobyte's answer works for me in lein2.

Comment: You should really upgrade to Lein 2. It uses the reply REPL which is really cool.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried just `Ctrl-C` ? It should work in your case.

**Update.** I've downgraded to Leiningen version 1.7.1. And it really quits repl by Ctrl-C. You should upgrade lein as Bozhidar Batsov said.

Comment: `Ctrl-C` exits the REPL for me.

Comment: Works for me using leiningen 2

Comment: Doesn't seem to work under Leiningen for Windows (in a cmd window).

Comment: I'm using the `clj` command, `Clojure CLI version 1.11.1.1237` and Ctrl-c quits the REPL. Seems like normal Ctrl-c behaviour is "[is not possible right now](https://clojureverse.org/t/interrupt-clj-evaluation-without-exiting-repl/4046)".

Answer (score 2):

For emacs users who come by this question later:

In Emacs + nrepl + lein2: hit <kbd>ctrl c</kbd> <kbd>ctrl b</kbd> to get back to your repl